Evaluating $\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]4}}{\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]2}\right)^3}$

Evaluate the expression, $$\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]4}}{\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]2}\right)^3}$$

I solved this problem as follow:
Let the expression be $t$, we have:
$$t^2=\dfrac{3+\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]4+2\sqrt{4+\sqrt[3]4+2\sqrt[3]2}{}}{(1+\sqrt[3]2)^3}$$
As, $4+\sqrt[3]4+2\sqrt[3]2=(\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]4)^2$,
$$t^2=\dfrac{3+\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]4+2(\sqrt[3]2+\sqrt[3]4)}{3+3\sqrt[3]2+3\sqrt[3]4}=1$$
It implies $t=1$ as the original expression is positive.
I'm looking for other approaches/ideas for solving this problem.

Hint: in terms of $x=\sqrt[3]{2}$ the numerator's second term is $\sqrt{x^3+x^2}=x\sqrt{1+x}$.

@J.G. Thanks for the hint. Your approach leads to answer much quicker than mine!

The trick is to recognize that $\sqrt{2 + \sqrt[3]4}=$$\sqrt{ \sqrt[3]{2}^3 + \sqrt[3]{2}^2}$$=\sqrt{\sqrt[3]2^2(\sqrt[3]2 + 1)}=\sqrt[3]2 \sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]2}$.  From there everything factors and cancels out very neatly.

$$\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt[3]4}}{\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]2}\right)^3}=\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]2}+\sqrt[3]2\sqrt{\sqrt[3]2+1}}{\left(\sqrt{1+\sqrt[3]2}\right)^3}=1$$
